# Error When Running composer update in CMD

Tags: php, composer-php

[image: Error Image]

Does anyone have this error when running composer update? What causing this? and how to fix it? Thank you

Expected the code to run composer update correctly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to update the composer.json and add a valid package description.
Also the package name should be like `vendor/packagename`

not like just `packagename`

Comment: thank you for your advice. but i just found the problem, i'm running composer update in false directory

Comment: Oh, It happens every once in a while. And It happens to everyone.

Comment: okay thank you, i'm already found the problem and solution too. thank you bro